# Formatting combobox's text

Tags: c#, user-interface, combobox

I've got quite tricky problem with my GUI application. I want my combobox to contain objects of a class I created, but at the same time it should display it's variable as name in the combobox.

This is how I add items to combobox:

```
publisherBox.Items.Add(p);
```

This is how I need to access it:

```
(Publisher)publisherBox.SelectedItem
```

And show in the combox it's name:

```
publisher.Name or something like that.
```

Is there any way it can be done?

Comment: tag the question with appropriate technology/application type like asp.net, wpf, winform etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ComboBox will use the ToString() method to display text. You can overwrite your ToString method in your class to show the name for example.